# Deleting parentheses in shell script

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I would like to create mechanism to delete parentheses, or parentheses and the text between them. For example:

before:

```
text0 text1 text2 (text3 text4)
```

after:

```
text0 text1 text2 text3 text4
```

or:

```
text0 text1 text2
```

I would like to test both options and other type of brackets but I'm not sure what tool should I use, Awk or Sed or maybe something else? I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Can brackets be nested?

Comment: Good question. Let's say yes but only brackets that are deeply nested - file may be json and curly braces will be preseted in every case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other half of your question,
deleting just the parentheses (but *not* the text between them):

```
echo 'text0 text1 text2 (text3 text4)' |
   sed 's/[()]//g'
```

Output:

```
text0 text1 text2 text3 text4
```

Answer (score 6):

To keep the text, this is enough:

```
tr -d '()'
```

To delete the text and parentheses:

```
sed 's/([^)]*)//g;s/  / /g'
```

If the text contains nested parenthesis like :

```
echo 'text0 (text1 (textA )) text2 (text3 text4) test5' |
  sed -e :A -e 's/([^()]*)//;tA' -e 's/  / /g'
```